# Sharing data service between components

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm new in Angular and have a problem. I have two components A and B. And SharedDataService.
In component A I get data from REST service and to share this data with component B I want to use SharedDataService.

Component A:

```
let data: Data;
this.restService.getData().subscribe(data => 
          {
            this.sharedService.addSharedData(data);
          } , error => console.error(error));
```

Component B:

```
let sharedData: Data;
     this.SharedService.getSharedData()
     .subscribe(ds => sharedData = ds);
```

And SharedService:

```
public sharedData: Data;

  constructor() { }

  addSharedData(data : Data) {
    this.sharedData = data;
  }

  getSharedData() : Observable<Data> {
    return of (this.sharedData);
  }
```

During debug I found out that Component B tries to get data several times earlier than Component A put there smth. How it works? I thought that subcribe always fetch data if it's changed. But why now it doesn't work?

P.S. Sharing data works well. For instance it works If I put this.sharedService.addSharedData(fakedata); before restService subscribtion in Component A

Comment: try to use same observable data in template (html) from service, use pure pipe in templates to show them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your `SharedService` to utilize `BehaviorSubject` and power of reactive programming.

```
  private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<Data> = new BehaviorSubject<Data>(null);

  addSharedData(data: Data) {
    this.sharedData.next(data);
  }

  getSharedData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.sharedData.asObservable();
  }
```

this way `SharedService` will keep track of your data seamlessly and notify all `getSharedData()` subscriptions whenever a new value arrives with `addSharedData(data: Data)`

also by using `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` any new subscriptions will receive last previous data. But be aware that until some data arrives with `addSharedData` method `getSharedData` will provide null value.

Comment: The same problem. I think it's because data in addSharedData method doesn't change

Comment: i updated my answer.  when we use `Subject` new subscription won't receive any previous data. `BehaviorSubject` solves that problem.